# export sql server query into excel grouped into different tabs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I have a sql query where I have the output of the query grouped by product. 
The output is something like this.

```
 ProductId  Date/Time Store
    1          xx       xx
    1     
    1
    2
    2
    2
    3
    and so on
```

I would like to export it into an excel file and I am using SSIS to export it into excel file ,

the requirement is that they would want each products information on a seperate tab in the excel file

Is there a way I can display the information related to each product in a seperate excel file ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891650/exporting-to-multiple-worksheets-using-ssis

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

[image]

You can use the same connection manager for both *Excel Destinations* and specify or create different worksheets in the same file.