# Export data to Excel in multiple sheets using SQL Server SSIS from start

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have two result sets from my SQL query that I need to export to Excel in multiple sheets. Every resultset should be exported to a separate Excel sheet.

How can I perform this task using SSIS or a stored procedure?

I can do this using c#. but I have to do it through SSIS. I am totally new to SSIS so I need to know it from the start.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: by m,ultiple sheets do you mean multiple workbooks ?

Comment: Multiple Sheets of one workbook.

Comment: SSIS can easily export to Excel: http://oakdome.com/programming/SSIS_DataTransform.php
I would create one dataflow for each sheet (unless you need to fill more then 2 sheets. In that case, add an for each loop).

Comment: Go through these link for the solution using SSIS.. [link](http://visakhm.blogspot.in/2013/09/exporting-sqlserver-data-to-multiple.html)  , [link] (http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/03/how-to-export-data-to-multiple-excel.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting to multiple worksheets using SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891650/exporting-to-multiple-worksheets-using-ssis)

Comment: This is not the duplicate Question. As i am totally new to this question and  I want to know the process of export to excel from start. but in that question we can not guess anything how to do it.

Comment: Yes SSIS will easily export to Excel and write data into multiple worksheets.  I have found the easiest approach to help coping with data formats and such is to have a template Excel file that has your worksheets and formatting, and potentially column headers ready to go.  Then copy that file and use the copied file as your destination.  Another gotcha is that you will have to do a data conversion to get any string data fields from SQL to Excel.